# how to close a jquery mobile page programmatically?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have been using `$.mobile.changePage()` to move to homepage, when i intent to close my jQuery mobile pages, which I think is not the correct way to deal with it. As when going back to page stack, I can see it again which I don't want.

What is the best way to close a JQM page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you my close? You want to remove them from dom?

Comment: not from dom but i want it to be removed from back stack. for example if i have a page to edit a store, i want to close it and go back to homepage when save button is tapped. currently when i press back button on android that page returns which i dont want.

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#yourpage", {changeHash: false});
```